# group data within a multidimensional javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a multidimensional javascript array that's filled with a lot of redundant data that I'd like grouped together by elements within itself...

```
// current array
pGroup = ([pm, name]); // [0][0] = pm0, [0][1] = name0 ... [n][0] = pmn, [n][1] = namen
```

My goal is to filter out all of the redundant pm's, then group the names into an array attached to their respective names.

I've tried several failed combinations of $.grep, $.filter, and have tinkered with underscore.js a bit to find a solution.. but as of yet I've come up empty.

Any guidance to a solution would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

// Current array

```
pGroup [

    [0]
    0: "Whimpenny, Walter"
    1: "105495-005_SMS M&S Option Year 1"
    ,

    [1]
    0: "Whimpenny, Walter"
    1: "105495-005_SMS M&S Option Year 2"
    , 

    [2]
    0: "Sukumar, Prasanna"
    1: "DISA-JCSS/Staff Aug-SO #203868" 

]
```

// requested result

```
pGroup [

    [0] 0: "Whimpenny, Walter" 1: ["105495-005_SMS M&S Option Year 1", "105495-005_SMS M&S Option Year 2"]

    [1] 0: "Sukumar, Prasanna" 1: ["DISA-JCSS/Staff Aug-SO #203868" ]

]
```

Comment: Could you give actual examples of input with its respective output?

Comment: Sure thing, I edited the post with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a functional solution using Lo-Dash:

```
var grouped = _.map(_.groupBy(pGroup, 0), function (el) {
    return [el[0][0], _.pluck(el, 1)];
});
```

[**JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/tuvoloxi/2/edit?js,console)

---

Alternatively, you could change the `return` line to the following to yield objects instead of arrays in the final product, as suggested by [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar):

```
return { name: el[0][0], values: _.pluck(el, 1) };
```

Comment: Solution worked perfectly, although I see @Barmar's point about using objects over arrays.

Comment: @Tabaker78 Yes, in this situation, objects would probably be a better choice. It would be easy enough to convert this solution to use objects instead, if you opted to go that route.

Answer (score 3):

Use an object keyed off the names to group the values.

```
var result_obj = {};
$.each(pGroup, function(i, e) {
    var name = e[0], val = e[1];
    if (result_obj[name]) {
        result_obj[name].push(val);
    } else {
        result_obj[name] = [val];
});
```

Then collect them back into an array.

```
pGroup = [];
$.each(result_obj, function(i, e) {
    pGroup.push([i, e]);
});
```

However, I suggest that you not use a multidimensional array for the results. Arrays should be used for uniform, ordered collections. Your second dimension is not uniform, it should be an object like this:

```
$.each(result_obj, function(i, e) {
    pGroup.push({name: i, values: e});
});
```