# Sum similar keys in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects like the following:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'P1',
        'value': 150
    },
    {
        'name': 'P1',
        'value': 150
    },
    {
        'name': 'P2',
        'value': 200
    },
    {
        'name': 'P3',
        'value': 450
    }
]
```

I need to add up all the values for objects with the same name. (Probably also other mathematical operations like calculate average.) For the example above the result would be:

```
[
    {
        'name': 'P1',
        'value': 300
    },
    {
        'name': 'P2',
        'value': 200
    },
    {
        'name': 'P3',
        'value': 450
    }
]
```

Comment: Try looping over the array, putting the values into a new array where the `name` is equal.  Either way, give it a try first.

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing, but you should be able to adapt the solutions here to what you're doing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792780/group-data-within-a-multidimensional-javascript-array/23793016#23793016

Comment: You can have a look at the MDN documentation to learn how to iterate over arrays and how to access object properties: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Iterating_over_arrays, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score 44, accepted):

First iterate through the array and push the 'name' into another object's property.  If the property exists add the 'value' to the value of the property otherwise initialize the property to the 'value'.  Once you build this object, iterate through the properties and push them to another array.

Here is some code:

```js
var obj = [
    { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 },
    { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 },
    { 'name': 'P2', 'value': 200 },
    { 'name': 'P3', 'value': 450 }
];

var holder = {};

obj.forEach(function(d) {
  if (holder.hasOwnProperty(d.name)) {
    holder[d.name] = holder[d.name] + d.value;
  } else {
    holder[d.name] = d.value;
  }
});

var obj2 = [];

for (var prop in holder) {
  obj2.push({ name: prop, value: holder[prop] });
}

console.log(obj2);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is quite an old question. I have started using Lodash (https://lodash.com/) since then. You can easily use the `sum` or `sumBy` Math functions to achieve what was asked in the original query

Comment: Hi My Object is like below how to process it?
var obj = [
    { 'name': 'P1', 'value': [150, 11] },
    { 'name': 'P1', 'value': [150, 12] },
    { 'name': 'P2', 'value': [200, 13] },
    { 'name': 'P3', 'value': [450, 14] }
];

Comment: while i like other solutions +1 for readability. It goes much furthar than a clever use of `Map`

Answer (score 36):

#### An ES2024 approach to group by `name`

You can first use [`Map.groupBy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/groupBy) to group your array by `name` into [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where each key in the map is a `name` from your objects and the value is an array of objects from your array with that `name` key. You can then use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) on the grouped `Map` to convert it into an array of objects, where for each object, you accumulate the objects to sum on `value` with the same `name` key using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

```js
const sumByKey = (arr, key, value) => {
  const grouped = Map.groupBy(arr, o => o[key]);
  return Array.from(
    grouped.values(),
    group => group.reduce((acc, obj) => ({...obj, [value]: (acc[value] ?? 0) + obj[value]}), {})
  );
}

const arr = [ { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 }, { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 }, { 'name': 'P2', 'value': 200 }, { 'name': 'P3', 'value': 450 } ];
console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'name', 'value')); // [ { "name": "P1", "value": 300 }, { "name": "P2", "value": 200 }, { "name": "P3", "value": 450 } ]
```

#### An ES6 approach to group by `name`:

You can convert your array of objects to a `Map` by using `.reduce()`. The Map has key-value pairs, where each key is the `name`, and each `value` is the accumulated sum of values for that particular `name` key. You can then easily convert the Map back into an array using `Array.from()`, where you can provide a mapping function that will take the keys/values of the Map and convert them into objects:

```js
const arr = [ { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 }, { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 }, { 'name': 'P2', 'value': 200 }, { 'name': 'P3', 'value': 450 } ];

const res = Array.from(arr.reduce(
  (m, {name, value}) => m.set(name, (m.get(name) || 0) + value), new Map
), ([name, value]) => ({name, value}));
console.log(res);
```

The above is quite compact and not necessarily the easiest to read. I would suggest putting it into a function so it's clearer what it's doing. If you're after more self-documenting code, using [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) can make the above easier to understand. The below function is also useful if you want to group or sum on keys with spaces in them:

```js
const arr = [ { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 }, { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 }, { 'name': 'P2', 'value': 200 }, { 'name': 'P3', 'value': 450 } ];

const sumByKey = (arr, key, value) => {
  const map = new Map();
  for(const obj of arr) {
    const currSum = map.get(obj[key]) || 0;
    map.set(obj[key], currSum + obj[value]);
  }
  const res = Array.from(map, ([k, v]) => ({[key]: k, [value]: v}));
  return res;
}

console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'name', 'value')); // 'name' = value to group by, 'value' = value to sum
```

---

#### Grouping by more than just `name`:

Here's an approach that should work if you have other overlapping properties other than just `name` (the keys/values need to be the same in both objects for them to "group"). It involves iterating through your array and reducing it to Map which holds key-value pairs. Each key of the new Map is a string of all the property values you want to group by, and so, if your object key already exists then you know it is a duplicate, which means you can add the object's current value to the stored object. Finally, you can use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to transform your Map of key-value pairs, to an array of just values:

```js
const arr = [{'name':'P1','value':150},{'name':'P1','value':150},{'name':'P2','value':200},{'name':'P3','value':450}];

const res = Array.from(arr.reduce((acc, {value, ...r}) => {
  const key = JSON.stringify(r);
  const current = acc.get(key) || {...r, value: 0};  
  return acc.set(key, {...current, value: current.value + value});
}, new Map).values());
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Excuse me,Is there a better way to implement it except using 'object.entries'?

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao you can use `JSON.stringify()`, I've added an implementation which does this

Comment: Excuse me, if you come across this type of data, it doesn't work  `[{
        id: 10,
        name: "abc",
        quantity: 2
    },
    {

        id: 10,
        name: "abc",
        quantity: 1
    }
] `

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao ah, I realized that I had a flaw in my logic. That is now fixed. To apply the above code to your data you can do it like so: https://jsfiddle.net/k478Ljgh/

Comment: @BaiClassmateXiao i also tried this answer which was very helpful to meet my requirement. i have customized this. i also need to do this for multiple keys.. Just Pass another parameter with value,value1 and so on..

Comment: may I ask what the complexity for this is?
Is it ideal for a situation where there may be many duplicates?
I am thinking of another approach where I first sort the arrays and then aggregate sum if the next item in the array is the same as the current item.

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal The first example is `O(N)`, where `N` is the length of `arr`.  The second example is `O(NK)` where `K` is the (max) number of properties in an object within the array. If you go for a sorting approach, the best complexity you can get (for comparison based sort) is `O(NlogN)`, which is larger than the `O(N)` solution

Comment: Any way to adapt it to find average instead of sum? please help. I really need an efficient algorithm for averaging with O(N)

Comment: @SiddharthAgrawal to calculate the average, you can group using the same approach as above, but. for each value store an object with the name, value and count (number of times you've seen an object with the same `name`), then use the second argument of array.from to convert these objects back into your desired format, where you can use the `count` to find the average. I made [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/3y81p7rk/)

Comment: How can I modify this code to work with object which keys has space in it? For example:
`const arr = [{'my name':'P1','my value':150},{'my name':'P1','my value':150},{'my name':'P2','my value':200},{'my name':'P3','my value':450}];`
Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ĐứcThanhNguyễn, you can use bracket notation `[]` to grab the key/value that you want to sum by. I've updated the second code snippet to use a function, you can use `'my name'` and `'my value'` as arguments when you call that.

Comment: I like your `sumByKey` @NickParsons but it returns a string, personally I'd think since its a `sum` it would/should return an `int`

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers Thanks, but it already does return a number type (without calling `Number()`) ? Or are you talking about some input data where it doesn't do that?

Comment: @NickParsons You know, I might be my fault for post manipulation, I think it was `toFixed(2)` that was recasting as string. I had to use `Number(v.toFixed(2))` not `Number(v).toFixed(2)`

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers I see, yeah, the toFixed would make it a strong. No worries, all good

Comment: @NickParsons I really liked one of your examples, built a function to tally strings via arrays and add `toFixed` option as well. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74681411/5079799 Thanks for the great starting point!

Comment: I ended up using --> `Number(Number(v).toFixed(2))`

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to accumulate results during each iteration.

```js
var arr = [{'name':'P1','value':150},{'name':'P1','value':150},{'name':'P2','value':200},{'name':'P3','value':450}];

var result = arr.reduce(function(acc, val){
    var o = acc.filter(function(obj){
        return obj.name==val.name;
    }).pop() || {name:val.name, value:0};
    
    o.value += val.value;
    acc.push(o);
    return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

I see these complicated reduce with Array from and Map and Set - this is far simpler

```js
const summed = arr.reduce((acc, cur, i) => {
  const item = i > 0 && acc.find(({name}) => name === cur.name)
  if (item) item.value += cur.value;
  else acc.push({ name: cur.name, value: cur.value }); // don't push cur here
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(arr); // not modified
console.log(summed);
```

```html
<script>
  const arr = [{
      'name': 'P1',
      'value': 150
    },
    {
      'name': 'P1',
      'value': 150
    },
    {
      'name': 'P2',
      'value': 200
    },
    {
      'name': 'P3',
      'value': 450
    }
  ]
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For some reason when I ran the code by @Vignesh Raja, I obtained the "sum" but also items duplicated. So, I had to remove the duplicates as I described below.

Original array:

```
arr=[{name: "LINCE-01", y: 70}, 
 {name: "LINCE-01", y: 155},
 {name: "LINCE-01", y: 210},
 {name: "MIRAFLORES-03", y: 232},
 {name: "MIRAFLORES-03", y: 267}]
```

Using @VigneshRaja's code:

```
var result = arr.reduce(function(acc, val){
    var o = acc.filter(function(obj){
        return obj.name==val.name;
    }).pop() || {name:val.name, y:0};

    o.y += val.y;
    acc.push(o);
    return acc;
},[]);

console.log(result);
```

First outcome:

```
result: [{name: "LINCE-01", y: 435},
 {name: "LINCE-01", y: 435},
 {name: "LINCE-01", y: 435},
 {name: "MIRAFLORES-03", y: 499},
 {name: "MIRAFLORES-03", y: 499}]
```

Removing the duplicates:

```
var finalresult = result.filter(function(itm, i, a) {
                            return i == a.indexOf(itm);
                        });
console.log(finalresult);
```

Finally, I obtained what I whished:

```
finalresult = [{name: "LINCE-01", y: 435},
 {name: "MIRAFLORES-03", y: 657}]
```

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

One more solution which is clean, I guess

```js
 

    var obj =  [
        { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 },
        { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 },
        { 'name': 'P2', 'value': 200 },
        { 'name': 'P3', 'value': 450 }
    ];

     var result = [];
Array.from(new Set(obj.map(x => x.name))).forEach(x => {

    result.push(obj.filter(y => y.name === x).reduce((output,item) => {
        let val = output[x] === undefined?0:output[x];
        output[x] =  (item.value +  val); 
       return output;
    },{}));

 })
      
            console.log(result);
```

if you need to keep the object structure same than,

```js
var obj =  [
    { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 },
    { 'name': 'P1', 'value': 150 },
    { 'name': 'P2', 'value': 200 },
    { 'name': 'P2', 'value': 1000 },
    { 'name': 'P3', 'value': 450 }
];

let output = [];
let result = {};
let uniqueName = Array.from(new Set(obj.map(x => x.name)));
uniqueName.forEach(n => {
   output.push(obj.filter(x => x.name === n).reduce((a, item) => {
      
       let val = a['name'] === undefined? item.value:a['value']+item.value;
        
        return {name:n,value:val};
    },{})
);
});

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

I have customized Mr Nick Parsons answer(Thanks for the idea). if you need to sum multiple key values.

```
var arr = [{'name':'P1','value':150,'apple':10},{'name':'P1','value':150,'apple':20},{'name':'P2','value':200,'apple':30},{'name':'P3','value':450,'apple':40}];

var res = Object.values(arr.reduce((acc, {value,apple , ...r}) => {
  var key = Object.entries(r).join('-');
  acc[key] = (acc[key]  || {...r, apple:0,value: 0});
  return (acc[key].apple += apple, acc[key].value += value, acc);
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

My data was not so organized as the example data. I faced a few issues such as I wanted to total the number of unique strings in a group and I have extra data that I don't care to tally.

I also found it a bit hard to substitute some of the answers demo data obj values for real world values depending on code readability. I decided I like @NickParsons answer best --> https://stackoverflow.com/a/57477448/5079799 and decided to add to it. Wasn't sure if this should be a new question like "Sum similar specific keys and/or sum strings in arrays" but this post seemed to be close enough that I felt an answer here was best.

I decided that using Arrays for string was best, and I made it an option for my function to DeDup array if desired. But now you can use `arr.length` for number of hits and as in my case, I will then also have further uses for that array as a collection based on the group.

I will likely be adding extra iterations over my Arr_Of_Objs but I like having this master function and then making smaller logical groups of Objs. I have a lot of cross-referencing/tallying and I tried making one large iteration where I did all the logic, and it became a total mess quickly.

I also added the ability to total strings if your object values happen to be cast as string vs int.

As well, the ability to pass `toFixed` to trim decimal places.

And `Criteria_Objs` for further restricting sums. Since you can't pass an operator, I made a single `if then` to check for `"=="` and use `==` as an operator. If you want more, you'd have to code them in, but should be easy to say add `>`

Here is some code:

```js
var arr = [
{
    'group': 'A',
    "Type": "A",
    "batch": "FOO_A",
    "name": "Unique_ID_1",
    'value': "150",
},
{
    'group': 'A',
    "Type": "A",
    "batch": "FOO_A",
    "name": "Unique_ID_11",
    'value': 150,
},
{
    'group': 'A',
    "Type": "A",
    "batch": "FOO_B",
    "name": "Unique_ID_2",
    'value': 150,
},
{
    'group': 'A',
    "Type": "A",
    "batch": "FOO_B",
    "name": "Unique_ID_22",
    'value': 150,
},
{
    'group': 'B',
    "Type": "A",
    "batch": "BAR_A",
    "name": "Unique_ID_A1",
    'value': 150,
},
{
    'group': 'B',
    "Type": "B",
    "batch": "BAR_A",
    "name": "Unique_ID_A11",
    'value': 150,
},
{
    'group': 'B',
    "Type": "A",
    "batch": "BAR_B",
    "name": "Unique_ID_B2",
    'value': 150,
},
{
    'group': 'B',
    "Type": "A",
    "batch": "BAR_B",
    "name": "Unique_ID_B22",
    'value': "150.016",
},
]

const sumByKey = (arr, key, value, DeDup_Str_Arr, TO_Fixed, Criteria_Arr_Of_Objs) => {

/*
var Criteria_Arr_Of_Objs = [
    {
        "crit_key": "Type",
        "crit_val": "A",
        "crit_operator": "==", 
    },
]
*/

var Is_Int = false
if (!isNaN(TO_Fixed) && TO_Fixed != null && TO_Fixed != false && TO_Fixed != "") {
    Is_Int = true
}
const map = new Map();
for (const obj of arr) {
    const currSum = map.get(obj[key]) || 0;
    var val = obj[value]
    var crit_passed = false
    if (Array.isArray(Criteria_Arr_Of_Objs) == true) {
        for (var ai = 0; ai < Criteria_Arr_Of_Objs.length; ++ai) {
            var crit_obj = Criteria_Arr_Of_Objs[ai]
            var check_val = obj[crit_obj['crit_key']]
            var crit_val = crit_obj['crit_val']
            var crit_operator = crit_obj['crit_operator']
            if (crit_operator == "==") {
                if (check_val == crit_val) {
                    crit_passed = true
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        crit_passed = true
    }
    if (crit_passed == true) {
        if (!isNaN(val)) {
            val = Number(val)
        }
        if (typeof val === 'string' || val instanceof String) {
            val = val + ","
        }
        map.set(obj[key], currSum + val);
    }
}
if (Is_Int == true) {
    var res = Array.from(map, ([k, v]) => ({ [key]: k, [value]: Number(Number(v).toFixed(2)) })); // 
} else {
    var res = Array.from(map, ([k, v]) => ({ [key]: k, [value]: v }));
}
var val = res[0][value]
if (typeof val === 'string' || val instanceof String) {
    for (var ai = 0; ai < res.length; ++ai) {
        var obj = res[ai]
        var val = obj[value]
        var vals_arr = val.split(",")
        vals_arr[0] = vals_arr[0].substring(1) //Removing leading 0
        vals_arr.pop() //trailing ","
        if (DeDup_Str_Arr == true) {
            let unique = [];
            for (let element of vals_arr) {
                if (Array.isArray(element) == true) {
                    for (let elm of element) { if (!unique.includes(elm)) { unique.push(elm) } }
                } else {
                    if (!unique.includes(element)) { unique.push(element) }
                }
            }
            obj[value] = unique
        } else {
            obj[value] = vals_arr
        }
    }
}
return res;
}

var Criteria_Arr_Of_Objs = [
{
    "crit_key": "Type",
    "crit_val": "A",
    "crit_operator": "==", 
},
]

console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'batch', 'value',false,false,Criteria_Arr_Of_Objs))
console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'batch', 'value'))
console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'batch', 'value', null, 2))
console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'batch', 'value', null, "2"))
console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'group', 'batch', null))
console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'group', 'batch', true))
console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'group', 'batch', true, "2"))
console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'group', 'batch', true, 2))
console.log(sumByKey(arr, 'group', 'value', true, 2))
```

Comment: For `crit_operator`, you could make it a function, eg: `crit_operator: (a, b) => a == b`, then you don't need to worry about changing the `sumByKey` function each time and you have more flexibility to code in any operator. You could use it something like `if(crit_operator(check_val, crit_val)) crit_passed = true;` in `sumByKey`

Comment: Thanks @NickParsons, I'll def take a look. Sometimes it takes longer to make the function then write the code. I haven't started actually putting this to the real-world code yet, but I am definitely newer than you at JavaScript i'd say. I can see how your answer is much clearer/concise, just wanted to share an alternative method with more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function () {
var arr = [
    {'name': 'P1', 'age': 150},
    {'name': 'P1', 'age': 150},
    {'name': 'P2', 'age': 200},
    {'name': 'P3', 'age': 450}
];
var resMap = new Map();
var result = [];
arr.map((x) => {
    if (!resMap.has(x.name))
        resMap.set(x.name, x.age);
    else
        resMap.set(x.name, (x.age + resMap.get(x.name)));
})
resMap.forEach((value, key) => {
    result.push({
        name: key,
        age: value
    })
})
console.log(result);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let ary = [
    {
        'key1': 'P1',
        'key2': 150
    },
    {
        'key1': 'P1',
        'key2': 150
    },
    {
        'key1': 'P2',
        'key2': 200
    },
    {
        'key1': 'P3',
        'key2': 450
    }
]
```

result array `let newAray = []`

```
for (let index = 0; index < ary.length; index++) {
        // console.log(ary[index].key1);
    
        for (let index2 = index + 1; index2 < ary.length; index2++) {
    
            if (ary[index2].key1 == ary[index].key1) {
                console.log('match');
                ary[index].key2 += ary[index2].key2;
                newAry = ary.filter( val => val !== ary[index2]);
    
                newAry = ary.filter(function (e) {
                    return  e !== ary[index2];
                });
    
            }
        }
    }
console.log(newAry)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here provide more generic version for this question

```js
/**
 * @param {(item: T) => string} keyFn
 * @param {(itemA: T, itemB: T) => T} mergeFn
 * @param {number[]} list
 */
function compress(keyFn, mergeFn, list) {
  return Array.from(
    list
      .reduce((map, item) => {
        const key = keyFn(item);

        return map.has(key) // if key already existed
          ? map.set(key, mergeFn(map.get(key), item)) // merge two items together
          : map.set(key, item); // save item in map
      }, new Map())
      .values()
  );
}

const testcase = [
  {
    name: "P1",
    value: 150,
  },
  {
    name: "P1",
    value: 150,
  },
  {
    name: "P2",
    value: 200,
  },
  {
    name: "P3",
    value: 450,
  },
];

console.log(
  compress(
    /* user define which is unique key */
    ({ name }) => name,
    /* how to merge two item together */
    (a, b) => ({ name: a.name, value: a.value + b.value }),
    /* array */
    testcase
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this approach for readability.

```js
const original = [
  { name: 'P1', value: 150 },
  { name: 'P1', value: 150 },
  { name: 'P2', value: 200 },
  { name: 'P3', value: 450 },
];

const aggregate = {};
original.forEach((item) => {
  if (aggregate[item.name]) {
    aggregate[item.name].value += item.value;
  } else {
    aggregate[item.name] = item;
  }
});


const summary = Object.values(aggregate);

console.log(original)
console.log(aggregate)
console.log(summary);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just build off the accepted answer with a more robust answer incase someone needs it

```js
let holder = {};

data.forEach(d => {

  if (!holder.hasOwnProperty(d.name)) {
    holder[d.name] = { name: d.name, invested: 0, returned: 0, nav: 0, irr: 0 };
  }

  holder[d.name] = {
    name: d.name,
    invested: holder[name].invested + d.invested,
    returned: holder[name].returned + d.returned,
    nav: holder[name].nav + d.nav,
    irr: holder[name].irr + d.irr,
  };
});

return Object.values(holder);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function uniqueItems(items) {
  var uniqueItems = [];
  for (let index = 0; index < items.length; index++) {
    const item = items[index];
    const found = uniqueItems.find(i => i.item_id == item.item_id);
    if (found) {
      found.quantity = found.quantity + item.quantity;
    } else {
      uniqueItems.push(item);
    }
  }
  return uniqueItems;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Easy way do it>
    
    const first = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  };
  
  const second = {
  a: 4,
  b: 3,
  }
  
  function sumObjects(...args) {
  const result = {};
  
  for (const object of args) {
    for (const key in object) {
      if (!result[key]) {
      result[key] = 0;
      }
      result[key] += object[key];
    }
  }
  
  return result;
  }
  
  const result = sumObjects(first, second);
  console.log(result);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding your names to a `TrueSet`.

```
import { TrueSet } from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = [
        {
            'name': 'P1',
            'value': 150
        },
        {
            'name': 'P1',
            'value': 150
        },
        {
            'name': 'P2',
            'value': 200
        },
        {
            'name': 'P3',
            'value': 450
        }
    ],

    expected =[
        {
            'name': 'P1',
            'value': 300
        },
        {
            'name': 'P2',
            'value': 200
        },
        {
            'name': 'P3',
            'value': 450
        }
    ];
```

The `let(item, nTimes)` method within the `TrueSet` enables the addition of the same item multiple times. This method accommodates fractional values as well. The `TrueSet` maintains a cumulative count of occurrences for each item and returns it through the method `n(item)`.

```
const 
    set = data.reduce((set, item) => set.let(item.name, item.value), 
            new TrueSet()),
    got = set.toArray()
        .map(name => ({name: name, value: set.n(name)}))
```

You can validate the proposed solution by:

```
assert.deepEqual(got, expected)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let arr = [
        {'name':'P1','value':150,'apple':10},
        {'name':'P1','value':150,'apple':20},
        {'name':'P2','value':200,'apple':30},
        {'name':'P2','value':600,'apple':30},
        {'name':'P3','value':450,'apple':40}
];

let obj = {}

arr.forEach((item)=>{
   if(obj[item.name]){
        obj[item.name].value = obj[item.name].value + item.value
   }else{
       obj[item.name] = item
   }
})

let valuesArr = Object.values(obj)
console.log(valuesArr);
```

**Output**

> [
> { name: "P1", value: 300, apple: 10 },
> { name: "P2", value: 800, apple: 30 },
> { name: "P3", value: 450, apple: 40 }   ]

Comment: if i print original array arr it be affected the original array  [
 `[
  { name: 'P1', value: 300, apple: 10 },
  { name: 'P1', value: 150, apple: 20 },
  { name: 'P2', value: 800, apple: 30 },
  { name: 'P2', value: 600, apple: 30 },
  { name: 'P3', value: 450, apple: 40 }
]`

Answer (score -1):

The method that Vignesh Raja posted will let you sum various values in an array of objects by the key or other property these method will work better

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

```js
let data= [
                {
                    'key1': 'P1',
                    'key2': 150
                },
                {
                    'key1': 'P1',
                    'key2': 150
                },
                {
                    'key1': 'P2',
                    'key2': 200
                },
                {
                    'key1': 'P3',
                    'key2': 450
                }
            ]
            
             var holder = []
                        data.forEach( index => {
                                const data = holder.find( i => i.key1=== index.key1)
                                if(!data){
                                    holder.push({key1:index.key1,key2:index.key2})
                                }else{
                                    data.key2 = parseInt(data.key2) + parseInt(index.key2)
                                }
                        });
            
            console.log(holder);
```