# Combine logic and increase sum

Tags: javascript, node.js

This logic is to combine Items ID into array. If ItemId is exit, it will increase the Sum. Is there a way to refactor this using map or something?

```
function combine2(order) {
    let combine = [];

    message2.Items.forEach((line) => {
        let id = line.ItemId;

        if (combine[id]) {
            combine[id].Sum += line.Sum;
        } else {
            combine[id] = {
                Id: id,
                Sum: line.Sum
            }
        }
    });

    return combine;
}

message2 = {
    Items: [ 
        {ItemId: "222", Sum: 2 },
        {ItemId: "222", Sum: 2 },
        {ItemId: "333", Sum: 3 }
    ]
}
```

Output

```
[ <222 empty items>,
    { Id: '222', Sum: 4 },
    <110 empty items>,
    { Id: '333', Sum: 3 } ]
```

I don't understand why is it showing <222 empty items> from the output

Comment: You are using the `ItemId` as index into an array, you are creating an array with `length` 334 in your example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum similar keys in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444738/sum-similar-keys-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for this:

```js
var message2 = {
    Items: [ 
        {ItemId: "222", Sum: 2 },
        {ItemId: "222", Sum: 2 },
        {ItemId: "333", Sum: 3 }
    ]
}

var res = message2.Items.reduce((acc, obj)=>{
    var existObj = acc.find(item => item.Id === obj.ItemId);
    if(existObj){
      existObj.Sum += obj.Sum;
      return acc;
    }
    acc.push({Id: obj.ItemId, Sum: obj.Sum});
    return acc;
},[]);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize combine as a json object, as in `let combine = {};`, rather than an array.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting 222 empty objects to being your array is because the else block you have 

   `} else {
            combine[id] = {
                Id: id,
                Sum: line.Sum
            }
        }`

What this code does is it takes your array, called `combine`, and adds something to the index at `id` so if `id` is equal to `222` as it is in the first case, it's going to insert an object like this `{ Id: '222', Sum: 4 }` at index 222, which is the 223rd thing in the array.

So you insert the object as the 223rd element in the array so that's why you have 222 empty objects to start

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using `Array.reduce()` and `Map()`:

```js
var message2 = {
    Items: [ 
        {ItemId: "222", Sum: 2 },
        {ItemId: "222", Sum: 2 },
        {ItemId: "333", Sum: 3 }
    ]
};

var result = message2.Items.reduce((map => (r, a) => {
        map.set(a.ItemId, map.get(a.ItemId) || r[r.push({ ItemId: a.ItemId, Sum: 0 }) - 1]);
        map.get(a.ItemId).Sum += a.Sum;
        return r;
})(new Map), []);
    
 console.log(result);
```