# How to add value of similar objects keys in es6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Like this is my array of objects:

```
var x = [
    {_id: 1, total: 25},
    {_id: 1, total: 22},
    {_id: 2, total: 4},
    {_id: 2, total: 32},
    {_id: 3, total: 56},
    {_id: 4, total: 21},
    {_id: 4, total: 58},
]
```

Now I want to achieve all total sum of similar object keys like this

```
[
    {_id: 1, total: 47},
    {_id: 2, total: 36},
    {_id: 3, total: 25}, 
    {_id: 4, total: 79},
]
```

Can anyone suggest how to do this on es6

Comment: Have you tried solving your problem yourself first?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sum similar keys in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444738/sum-similar-keys-in-an-array-of-objects)

Answer (score 0):

Use `reduce`. `reduce` is an array method that can transform an array into something else, i.e. another array that can have different length. `map` will always return an array with the same number of elements. And `filter` can return an array that has less elements but the elements will be unchanged.

Reduce gives you the more flexible behavior. You can change the elements and you can store them in whatever way you like.

```js
const result = x.reduce((acc, el) => {
  const index = acc.findIndex(({_id}) => el._id === _id);
  if (index > -1) {
    acc[index].total += el.total;
  } else {
    acc.push({...el});
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

In case if this code would run often and on large arrays, you can use more performant but a little more complex solution where we use a hash table to store the data:

```js
    var x = [
        {_id: 1, total: 25},
        {_id: 1, total: 22},
        {_id: 2, total: 4},
        {_id: 2, total: 32},
        {_id: 3, total: 56},
        {_id: 4, total: 21},
        {_id: 4, total: 58},
    ]
    
const temp = {};
for (const el of x) {
  temp[el._id] = (temp[el._id] || 0) + el.total;
}

const result = Object.entries(temp).map(([_id, total]) => ({_id, total}));

console.log(result);
```

But before starting optimizing you should always check if it's worth doing by running perf tools.

Comment: This question is clearly a duplicate. Please mark it as such instead of answering it.

Comment: @str what's wrong with answering? I do it partially for myself to see if I can explain the solution clearly. Even if you mark this question as duplicate it won't disappear from SO. But of course it is a duplicate so I'm more than happy to mark it as such.

Comment: ["The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in *one* place."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates)