# How to merge array object value to array if have a same id

Tags: javascript, lodash

I want to merge value to array if it have a same id.
I have one array of objects like this.

```
[ 
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Rosie',
 },
 { 
   id: 'Jane',
   type: 'human',
   favorite: null,
 },
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Lisa',
 },
 { 
   id: 'Steve',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Jennie',
 },
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Jisoo',
 },
]
```

and I want to merge key `favorite` from string to array.
I want output like this

```
[ 
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: ['Rosie', 'Lisa', 'Jisoo'],
 },
 { 
   id: 'Jane',
   type: 'human',
   favorite: null,
 },
 { 
   id: 'Steve',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: ['Jennie'],
 }
```

and i try to write code like this: (from: [Sum similar keys in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444738/sum-similar-keys-in-an-array-of-objects) )

```
var obj = [
    {
      id: 'Tony',
      type: 'hero',
      favorite: 'Rosie',
    },
    {
      id: 'Jane',
      type: 'human',
      favorite: null,
    },
    {
      id: 'Tony',
      type: 'hero',
      favorite: 'Lisa',
    },
    {
      id: 'Steve',
      type: 'hero',
      favorite: 'Jennie',
    },
    {
      id: 'Tony',
      type: 'hero',
      favorite: 'Jisoo',
    },
  ];

  var holder = {};
  const ar = []
  obj.forEach(function (d) {
    if (holder.hasOwnProperty(d.id)) {
      holder[d.id] = ar.push(holder[d.id] + d.favorite);
    } else {
      holder[d.id] = d.favorite;
    }
  });

  var obj2 = [];

  for (var prop in holder) {
    obj2.push({ name: prop, favorite: holder[prop] });
  }

  console.log(obj2);
```

but out put is

```
[ { name: 'Tony', favorite: 2 },
  { name: 'Jane', favorite: null },
  { name: 'Steve', favorite: 'Jennie' } ]
```

How can i do this ?

Comment: What have you done so far? Isnt `jane`'s favorite should be `[null]`?

Comment: i try to write code from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444738/sum-similar-keys-in-an-array-of-objects, and `Jane` dont have a favourite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a single [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and would most likely be the most simple and performant approach:

```js
var data = [ { id: 'Tony', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Rosie', }, { id: 'Jane', type: 'human', favorite: null, }, { id: 'Tony', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Lisa', }, { id: 'Steve', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Jennie', }, { id: 'Tony', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Jisoo', }, ]

let result = data.reduce((r, {id,type,favorite}) => {
  r[id] = r[id] || {id, type, favorite: []}
  r[id].favorite.push(favorite)
  return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

The idea is to "group by" the `id` and then keep pushing to the `favorites` array on each iteration.

For `ES5` you can do it in similar fashion:

```js
var data = [ { id: 'Tony', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Rosie', }, { id: 'Jane', type: 'human', favorite: null, }, { id: 'Tony', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Lisa', }, { id: 'Steve', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Jennie', }, { id: 'Tony', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Jisoo', }, ]

let result = data.reduce(function(r, c){
   r[c.id] = r[c.id] || {id: c.id, type: c.type, favorite: []}
   r[c.id].favorite.push(c.favorite)
   return r
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

There really is no need for `lodash` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Group by the `id` with `_.group()`, and then merge each group using `_.map()` and `_.mergeWith()`, and collect `favorite` to an array:

```js
const data = [{"id":"Tony","type":"hero","favorite":"Rosie"},{"id":"Jane","type":"human","favorite":null},{"id":"Tony","type":"hero","favorite":"Lisa"},{"id":"Steve","type":"hero","favorite":"Jennie"},{"id":"Tony","type":"hero","favorite":"Jisoo"}]

const result = _(data)
  .groupBy('id')
  .map(g => _.mergeWith({}, ...g, (o, s, k) => {
    if(k !== 'favorite') return // non favorite key are not collected to an array
    
    if(_.isNil(s)) return o // don't add null or undefined to array
    
    return [].concat(o || [], s) // concat other values to array
  }))
  .value()
  
console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the array and construct a new array after converting `favorite` attribute into an array, then for next elements with the same id, push to `favorite` array

```js
let users = [{id: 'Tony', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Rosie',}, {id: 'Jane', type: 'human', favorite: null,}, {id: 'Tony', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Lisa',}, {id: 'Steve', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Jennie',}, {id: 'Tony', type: 'hero', favorite: 'Jisoo',},];

// To combine friends of the same user in an array at property friendNames
let merged = {};
for (let user of users) {
    if (typeof merged[user.id] === 'undefined') {
        user.favorite = [user.favorite];
        merged[user.id] = user;
    } else {
        merged[user.id].favorite.push(user.favorite)
    }
}

console.log(Object.values(merged));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `map` and `Set` to get this result.

First we create a new unique `Set` using the `id` field.

We seed a new new `array` from this and call the `map` method.

```js
const arr = [ 
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Rosie',
 },
 { 
   id: 'Jane',
   type: 'human',
   favorite: null,
 },
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Lisa',
 },
 { 
   id: 'Steve',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Jennie',
 },
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Jisoo',
 },
];

const masterArr = [...new Set(arr.map((e) => e.id))].map(a => ({
  id: a,
  type: arr.find(x => x.id === a).type,
  favorites: arr.filter(x => x.id === a).map(y => y.favorite)
}));

console.log(masterArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce on the array.

```
const arr = [ 
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Rosie',
 },
 { 
   id: 'Jane',
   type: 'human',
   favorite: null,
 },
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Lisa',
 },
 { 
   id: 'Steve',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Jennie',
 },
 { 
   id: 'Tony',
   type: 'hero',
   favorite: 'Jisoo',
 },
]
const out = arr.reduce((result, el)=> {
    const id = result.findIndex(e => e.id ===el.id)

    if(id> -1){
        result[id] = {...result[id], favorite: [...result[id].favorite, el.favorite]}
    } else {result.push({...el, favorite: [el.favorite].filter(x => x) })}
    return result
}, [])
console.log(out)
```