# Cumulative sum of values belonging to a same field in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I  have an array in the following format that has x and y values with a data field and I am looking to convert into an array that adds up all the individual value over a specific data, and then shows a cumulative value (summing over that date and then adding the value to the previous dates). Eg.

```
data_array = [
{xvalue: 10, yvalue: 5, date: "12/2"},
{xvalue: 10, yvalue: 5, date: "12/2"},
{xvalue: 8, yvalue: 3, date: "12/3"},
{xvalue: 10, yvalue: 5, date: "12/3"},
{xvalue: 6, yvalue: 1, date: "12/4"},
{xvalue: 20, yvalue: 3, date: "12/4"},
]
```

New array

```
new_data = [
{xvalue: 20, yvalue: 10, date: "12/2"}
{xvalue: 38, yvalue: 18, date: "12/3"}
{xvalue: 64, yvalue: 22, date: "12/4"}
]
```

What will be a way to do this efficiently? Currently I have the following way that works but feel like its not the best implementation

```
var temp = {}
var obj = null
for (var i=0; i<data_array.length; i++){
    obj = data_array[i];

    if (!temp[obj.date]) {
        temp[obj.date]=obj;
    } 
    else {
        temp[obj.date].xvalue += obj.xvalue;
        temp[obj.date].yvalue += obj.yvalue
    }
}
var result = [];
for (var prop in temp){
    result.push(temp[prop]);
}
console.log("result", result)

for (var i=0; i< result.length; i++){
  if (i!=0){
    result[i].xvalue +=result[i-1].xvalue;
    result[i].yvalue +=result[i-1].yvalue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use the `Array.prototype.reduce` function

Comment: can you tell us what you've tried please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum javascript object propertyA values with same object propertyB in array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19233283/sum-javascript-object-propertya-values-with-same-object-propertyb-in-array-of-ob)

Comment: [Sum similar keys in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444738)

Comment: Hi everyone - I updated my implementation but would love some feedback if there is a better way to do this

Answer (score 3):

```js
data_array = [
{xvalue: 10, yvalue: 5, date: "12/2"},
{xvalue: 10, yvalue: 5, date: "12/4"},
{xvalue: 8, yvalue: 3, date: "12/3"},
{xvalue: 10, yvalue: 5, date: "12/2"},
{xvalue: 6, yvalue: 1, date: "12/3"},
{xvalue: 20, yvalue: 3, date: "12/2"},
];
var reduced =  data_array.reduce(function(final,item){
  if(final[item.date]){
    final[item.date] = {cummxvalue: item.xvalue+final[item.date].cummxvalue, cummyvalue: item.yvalue+final[item.date].cummyvalue, date: item.date};
  }else{
    final[item.date] = {cummxvalue: item.xvalue, cummyvalue: item.yvalue, date: item.date};
  }
return final;
},{});
var new_data = Object.values(reduced);
console.log(new_data);
```

Comment: may I suggest using the `Object.values(reduced)`, instead of the for-loop at the end?

Comment: Thanks @Geetanjali! I updated my question with my implementation as I also need to do cumulative sum over the date. Thoughts on that implmentation?

Answer (score 1):

You may loop through the array and add `xvalue`s and `yvalue`, and copy into a new array as you go if the elements donot have the same `date` value. You will also need to sort the array incase it's not already sorted as your first example.

```js
const data_array = [
  {xvalue: 10, yvalue: 5, date: "12/2"},
  {xvalue: 10, yvalue: 5, date: "12/4"},
  {xvalue: 8, yvalue: 3, date: "12/3"},
  {xvalue: 10, yvalue: 5, date: "12/2"},
  {xvalue: 6, yvalue: 1, date: "12/3"},
  {xvalue: 20, yvalue: 3, date: "12/2"}
]

let new_data = [];
let cummxvalue = 0;
let cummyvalue = 0;

data_array.sort( (a, b) => a.date > b.date );

for( const obj of data_array) {
  let o = new_data.find(o => o.date === obj.date);
  cummxvalue += obj.xvalue;
  cummyvalue += obj.yvalue;

  if(!o) {
    new_data.push({cummxvalue: cummxvalue, cummyvalue: cummyvalue, date: obj.date});
  }
  else {
    o.cummxvalue = cummxvalue;
    o.cummyvalue = cummyvalue;
  }
}

console.log(new_data)
```