# JS sum values in array of arrays where 2 keys are important

Tags: javascript, arrays

In array I have there are dates , products and products quantities. Sometimes the same products repeat the same day and I want to sum them but only if the date is the same.
My array:

```
[
    {date:"day2",sku:"product1",qty:1},
    {date:"day1",sku:"product1",qty:1},
    {date:"day1",sku:"product2",qty:1},
    {date:"day2",sku:"product2",qty:1},
    {date:"day1",sku:"product1",qty:1},
    {date:"day2",sku:"product2",qty:1},
    {date:"day2",sku:"product2",qty:1},
    {date:"day3",sku:"product1",qty:3}
]
```

and expected output:

```
[
    {date:"day1",sku:"product1",qty:2},
    {date:"day1",sku:"product2",qty:1},
    {date:"day2",sku:"product1",qty:1},
    {date:"day2",sku:"product2",qty:3},
    {date:"day3",sku:"product1",qty:3}
]
```

Comment: For a specific answer in the duplicate, you can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57477448/5648954) where it shows all keys being used for the sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `reduce` and then take `Object.values()`:

```js
var array=[ {date:"day2",sku:"product1",qty:1}, {date:"day1",sku:"product1",qty:1}, {date:"day1",sku:"product2",qty:1}, {date:"day2",sku:"product2",qty:1}, {date:"day1",sku:"product1",qty:1}, {date:"day2",sku:"product2",qty:1}, {date:"day2",sku:"product2",qty:1}, {date:"day3",sku:"product1",qty:3}];

var result = Object.values(array.reduce((acc, {qty,...rest})=>{
   const key = Object.values(rest).join('|');
   acc[key] = acc[key] || {...rest, qty:0};
   acc[key].qty+=qty;
   return acc;
},{}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: nice use of destructuring 