# Javascript searching task

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Task: You have array with key: value pairs like:

```
arr = ["x:1", "y:2", "a:5", "x:5", "z:0"]
```

You must sum all the same keys  so it will be:

```
["x:6","y:2","a:5","z:0"]
```

on output.

I finish this task but its complicate. I have solved the task but I am looking for a simpler solution

```js
var a = ["x:1", "y:2", "a:5", "x:5", "z:0"]

function saberi(niz) {
  let povratni = [];
  for (clan of niz) {
    let razdvojen = clan.split(":");
    let key = razdvojen[0]
    let value = razdvojen[1]

    let provjera = false
    for (let i = 0; i < povratni.length; i++) {
      let razdvojen2 = povratni[i].split(":")
      let key2 = razdvojen2[0]
      let value2 = razdvojen2[1]

      if (key2 == key) {
        console.log("uso")
        let novavrijednost = parseFloat(value) + parseFloat(value2)
        povratni[i] = key2 + ":" + novavrijednost
        provjera = true
        break
      }
    }
    if (!provjera) {
      povratni.push(clan)
    }
  }
  console.log(povratni)
  return povratni
}
saberi(a)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444738/sum-similar-keys-in-an-array-of-objects

Comment: If the code works but you are looking for something better, this belongs on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use objects to make this easier. Each character to the left of the colon `:` will be a key in the object, and the number to the right of the colon will be the value, which you can accumulate to the value from the object at the given key.

To start, you can loop through your `arr` using a [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop, and for each string in your array, use [`.split(":")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to break the string into its key and value components. You can then grab the current value stored at the key from the object (`grouped`) by using `grouped[key]`. If the value doesn't exist, you can default it to 0 using `|| 0`. Once you have the current value stored in the object, you can add the number version of the value to the accumulated value, and store that new value in the object at the key `key`.

Once you have your object, you can grab the entries to get an array of the form `[[key, value], [key2, value2], ...]`, which you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) on to convert each `[key, value]` to a string of the form `key:value`:

```js
const arr = ["x:1", "y:2", "a:5", "x:5", "z:0"];

const grouped = {};
for(const str of arr) {
  const [key, num] = str.split(":");
  grouped[key] = (grouped[key] || 0) + Number(num);
}

const res = Object.entries(grouped).map(entry => entry.join(":"));
console.log(res);
```

The same concept above can be accomplished using [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) instead of an object, as well as [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to map the entries of the Map to an array:

```js
const arr = ["x:1", "y:2", "a:5", "x:5", "z:0"];

const res = Array.from(arr.reduce((map, str) => {
  const [key, val] = str.split(":");
  return map.set(key, (map.get(key) || 0) + +val);
}, new Map), entry => entry.join(':'));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. Traverse the array and split each item by `colon(:)`. Then group it by key to count sum. At last, transform the object into a `key-value` pair array using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) method and then map and join it by `colon(:)`.

```js
const arr = ['x:1', 'y:2', 'a:5', 'x:5', 'z:0'];

const ret = Object.entries(
  arr.reduce((prev, c) => {
    const p = prev;
    const [k, v] = c.split(':');
    p[k] = p[k] ?? 0;
    p[k] += +v;
    return p;
  }, {})
).map((x) => x.join(':'));
console.log(ret);
```