# Count the number of occurrences and add it to grouped objects in a JSON array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

Here's my input value -

```
var input = [
    {
      status: 'yes',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      score: 2,
      rank: 2,
    },
    {
      status: 'yes',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      score: 9,
      rank: 2,
    },
    {
      status: 'yes',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      score: 8,
      rank: 2,
    },
    {
      status: 'no',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      score: 12,
      rank: 3,
    },
    {
      status: 'no',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      score: 9,
      rank: 3,
    },
    {
      status: 'no',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      score: 5,
      rank: 3,
    },
  ]
```

And here's what I'm trying to get as an output value -

```
  [
    {
      status: 'yes',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      occurrence: 1,
      rank: 2,
    },
    {
      status: 'yes',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      occurrence: 2,
      rank: 2,
    },
    {
      status: 'no',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
      occurrence: 2,
      rank: 3,
    },
    {
      status: 'no',
      data: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      occurrence: 1,
      rank: 3,
    },
  ]
```

The idea is to -

1. Remove the `score` parameter from all the objects
2. Add the `occurrence` parameter to all the objects
3. Assign the "occurrence" value i.e. the number of times we see the same `data` being repeated as per each of the `status`

Here's the code that I'm using (adopted from the 2nd half of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57477448/10713297)) -

```
const res = Array.from(input.reduce((acc, {score, ...r}, index) => {
  const key = JSON.stringify(r);
  const current = acc.get(key) || {...r, occurrence: 0};  
  return acc.set(key, {...current, occurrence: current.occurrence + index});
}, new Map).values());
console.log(res);
```

But that's producing an unexpected output that looks like this -

```
[
  {
    "status": "yes",
    "data": ["a","b","c","d"],
    "rank": 2,
    "occurrence": 0
  },
  {
    "status": "yes",
    "data": ["a","b","c"],
    "rank": 2,
    "occurrence": 3
  },
  {
    "status": "no",
    "data": ["a","b","c","d"],
    "rank": 3,
    "occurrence": 8
  },
  {
    "status": "no",
    "data": ["a","b","c"],
    "rank": 3,
    "occurrence": 4
  }
]
```

There's something that I'm missing to get the correct occurrences & I can't for the life of me understand what.

Comment: The [tag:json] tag is not intended for this.

Comment: is the data array is alwys sorted ? - `data:['a','b','c']` vs  `data:['a','c','b']` - ?

Comment: Why are you adding index? Shouldn't that be 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do that this way

```js
const
  input = 
  [ { status: 'yes', data: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ], score:  2, rank: 2 } 
  , { status: 'yes', data: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],      score:  9, rank: 2 } 
  , { status: 'yes', data: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],      score:  8, rank: 2 } 
  , { status: 'no',  data: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ], score: 12, rank: 3 } 
  , { status: 'no',  data: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ],      score:  9, rank: 3 } 
  , { status: 'no',  data: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ], score:  5, rank: 3 } 
  ] 
, result = input.reduce((a,{status,data,rank}) =>
  {
  let same = a.find( x => x.status === status 
                       && x.rank   === rank
                       && JSON.stringify(x.data) === JSON.stringify(data) 
                      )
  if (!same)
    a.push({ status, data: [...data], occurrence: 1, rank })
  else 
    same.occurrence++
  return a 
  },[])

console.log( result )
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important;top:0}
```

Answer (score -1):

I really didn't catch what did you want to do with `occurence` value. In your example you were showing:

`status: 'no', data: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], occurrence: 2,`

And why is here `occurence` equals `2` whereas 'no' is the first status with this value?

At first try to remove `current.occurrence + index` and leave just `current.occurrence` if it will be always zero it will be correct to make next steps to calculate what you want.

I doubt that you need `index` there. Try to explain, and it helps to provide a decision.