# How to get the sum of a key in an array of object and remove duplicates of consecutive objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

I have a main array -

```
const arr = [
    {  description: 'Senior', amount: 50 },
    {  description: 'Senior', amount: 50 },
    {  description: 'Adult', amount: 75 },
    {  description: 'Adult', amount: 35 },
    {  description: 'Infant', amount: 25 },
    {  description: 'Senior', amount: 150 }
]
```

I want help with an es6 operation which will add the amount based on the key(description) and remove the duplicates.

Result array will somewhat look like -

```
const newArr = [
        {  description: 'Senior', amount: 120 },
        {  description: 'Adult', amount: 110 },
        {  description: 'Infant', amount: 25 },
        {  description: 'Senior', amount: 150 }
]
```

I have been using the reduce operator to achieve this using the solutions from below, but that removes the non-consecutive objects as well.

It would be really helpful if someone can help me with some es6 operators to perform the same operation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum similar keys in an array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24444738/sum-similar-keys-in-an-array-of-objects)

Comment: the solution is  very simple with reduce and object.values as I have answered

Answer (score 3):

```js
const arr = [
  { description: "Senior", amount: 50 },
  { description: "Senior", amount: 50 },
  { description: "Adult", amount: 75 },
  { description: "Adult", amount: 35 },
  { description: "Infant", amount: 25 },
];

const result = Object.values(
  arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item.description] = acc[item.description]
      ? { ...item, amount: item.amount + acc[item.description].amount }
      : item;
    return acc;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

- Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), iterate over the array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the key is the `description` and the value is the record with total `amount`
- Using [`Map#values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values), get the list of grouped objects

```js
const arr = [ { description: 'Senior', amount: 50 }, { description: 'Senior', amount: 50 }, { description: 'Adult', amount: 75 }, { description: 'Adult', amount: 35 }, { description: 'Infant', amount: 25 } ];

const res = [...
  arr.reduce((map, current) => {
    const { description } = current;
    const grouped = map.get(description);
    if(!grouped) {
      map.set(description, { ...current });
    } else {
      map.set(description, { ...grouped, amount: grouped.amount + current.amount })
    }
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  .values()
];

console.log(res);
```

Comment: What if there are other keys which I need in in the object. Like {description: 'xyz', amount: 100, type: 'credit', verifed: true}

Comment: @AritraGanguly then you can use the spread operator as shown in the edit

Answer (score 0):

You may just use this snippet

```
array.filter((item, index) => array.indexOf(item) === index);
```

Refer to this [link](https://www.samanthaming.com/tidbits/43-3-ways-to-remove-array-duplicates/) for more details. Or just copy [this solution](https://javascript.tutorialink.com/sum-similar-keys-in-an-array-of-objects/).